# ArrayOutOfBoundsException when removing Objects from a JTable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I'm a complete newbie to Java. I've only been learning it for half a year now. Right now I am working on a Project for school and I've hit a complete wall:

I am basically making a Program to manage your own Books. I have a class that is "Books", which holds the data for the book objects. Then there's the class "Library" which holds an ArrayList of Books. For the TableModel, I am using a class ("LibraryTableModel") that extends AbstractTableModel. I then have a GUI class wich displays the table.

The table actually works, but there are two instances where the program crashes:

When I add a Book to an empty Library, the table doesn't update. However, the Book IS added when I start the program anew (I save the Library class as a .ser file).

Then the instance which I am asking about: I have a button that removes Books from the table. the Button itself works fine, but when I remove a book, the program throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. When I create the table anew, it updates and the book is removed. What is the problem here, why does the program crash instead of update the table?

Code for TableModel:

```
public class LibraryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
private String[] columnNames = {"Titel", "Autor", "Status", "Genre", "Verlag", "Seitenzahl", "ISBN", "Sprache", "Bewertung"};
private Object[][] data = {};
ArrayList<Book> lib;

public LibraryTableModel(Library l)
{
    //This Method returns the ArrayList in the Library class
    lib = l.getList();

    int libSize = lib.size();
    data = new Object[bib.size()][];

    for (Book b : lib)
    {
        int index = bib.indexOf(b);
        //(...)
        //CODE HERE gets all the data that is supposed to be displayed 
        //from each book in the ArrayList      
        Object[] oA = {tit, aut, sta, gen, ver, sei, isb, spr, bew};

        data[index] = oA;
    }
}

public int getColumnCount()
{
    return columnNames.length;
}

public int getRowCount()
{
    return data.length;
}

public String getColumnName(int col) 
{
    return columnNames[col];
}

public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) 
{
    return data[row][col];
    //When I try to remove a Book, the ArrayOutOfBounds Exception comes from here
}

public Class getColumnClass(int c) 
{
    return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
}

public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) 
{
    data[row][col] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}

public void removeRow(int row)
{
    lib.remove(row);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
}
```

Code in the GUI class that is revolving around the table and the tablemodel:

```
public class GUI implements ActionListener
{
JTable table;
LibraryTableModel model;
TableRowSorter<BibliothekTableModel> sorter;
Library lib;
JMenuItem deleteBook;
```

(...)  The Library is loaded through the .ser file

```
public void showTable() //This method is envoked in the GUI constructor through pressing a button
 {
    model = new LibraryTableModel(lib);
    table.setModel(model);

    deleteBook.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            model.removeRow(row);

            //Code that saves the library at this point

            table.setModel(new LibraryTableModel(lib));
        }
    });

    popupMenu.add(deleteBook);
    table.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);

    sorter = new TableRowSorter<BibliothekTableModel>(model);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);
    JScrollPane scrollTable = new JScrollPane(table);

    //Next is code, that adds this ScrollPane to my Frame
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I add a Book to an empty Library, the table doesn't update. However, the Book IS added when I start the program anew (I save the Library class as a .ser file).

There is no information provided which demonstrates how this works...and what's a `.ser` file?

> Then the instance which I am asking about: I have a button that
>   removes Books from the table. the Button itself works fine, but when I
>   remove a book, the program throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. When I
>   create the table anew, it updates and the book is removed. What is the
>   problem here, why does the program crash instead of update the table?

There are two issues...

First, because you are using a `RowSorter` on the table, the visual row index returned by `JTable#getSelectedRow` and the physical row index in the model won't be the same, you need to use [`JTable#convertRowIndexToModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int))

```
int row = table.getSelectedRow();
row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
model.removeRow(row);

//Code that saves the library at this point
```

Second, you're removing the book from the `lib`, but not updating the internal cache...

```
public void removeRow(int row)
{
    lib.remove(row);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
}
```

The model isn't using the `lib` as it's source for the data, but is using the `data` array, which you have not updated.

While you could simply rebuild the `data` array, a better solution would be to get rid of it and use the `lib` directly, for example...

```
public class LibraryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = {"Titel", "Autor", "Status", "Genre", "Verlag", "Seitenzahl", "ISBN", "Sprache", "Bewertung"};
    private Object[][] data = {};

    private Library lib;

    public LibraryTableModel(Library l) {
        lib = l;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return lib.getList().size();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Book book = lib.getList().get(row);
        Object value = null;
        switch (col) {
            case 0:
                value = ...;
                break;
            case 1:
                value = ...;
                break;
            case 2:
                value = ...;
                break;
            case 3:
                value = ...;
                break;
            case 4:
                value = ...;
                break;
            case 5:
                value = ...;
                break;
            case 6:
                value = ...;
                break;
            case 7:
                value = ...;
                break;
            case 8:
                value = ...;
                break;
        }
        return value;
//When I try to remove a Book, the ArrayOutOfBounds Exception comes from here
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        // Don't do this, know the actualy value and return it
        // Otherwise you could end up with a NullPointerException
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        // Use a simular technquie to getValueAt to extract the Book for the give
        // row and update the Book's attributes
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    public void removeRow(int row) {
        lib.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }

}
```

Comment: I edited the code you suggested and took out the dangerous code you described. Now, the code works; However, the table does not update itself. 

I used the .setModel to update the table when I added a Book to the library, and it worked. How else can I update the table after I add or remove data?

Comment: @Ikeaner I've update the answer, you were updating the `lib` `ArrayList`, but not the `Library` class, also you were not updating the models internal cache, see updates for suggestions...

Comment: First of all, thank you SO much! I really wasn't getting the whole TableModel thing and I think I got behind it a little more now! Your suggestion works, if the Library is empty at the beginning of the program, I can add books without any problems. I now am also able to delete books from the table!

One problem I newly encountered was, that when I deleted ALL the books from the table, the table was not redrawn when I clicked the button to call showTable() after I removed it from the gui. But I think I might have to look for the solution there in my GUI code. THANK YOU SO MUCH AGAIN!

Comment: If you remove anything from the `Library`, you need to get the model to update.  You should create a method in you model which can "clear" the `Library` and call the [`AbstractTableModel#fireTableDataChanged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged()) method

Comment: Actually it works and I have the fireTableDataChanged in the removeRow() method, it's just that when i manually remove all books from the list, the list doesn't show up again when I call showTable(). However, when I restart the program, it works. I think however, that is a problem with code in my GUI class, unless you have another suggestion to how that happens? Or maybe I just didn't understand your last comment?

Comment: I wouldn't use `fireTableDataChanged` in the `removeRow`, as it forces the entire table to be re-drawn, might not be a big issue on small data sets, but can really slow things down when you have a large data set.  The table not showing up could be an issue with the layout managers, it's hard to tell. Generally, I would focus on only updating the model wherever possible, and not replacing the `JTable` on the screen...